# Running long tasks without freezing the UI

Tags: wpf, task, microsoft-metro

I am trying to perform an action in the background, without freezing the UI.

Of course, I could use BackgroundWorker for this.

However, I'd like to do it with the Task API only.

I tried:

```
async void OnTestLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await LongOperation();
}
// It freezes the UI
```

and

```
async void OnTestLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var task = Task.Run(()=> LongOperation());
   task.Wait();
}


// It freezes the UI
```

So should I go back to BackgroundWorker? Or is there a solution using Tasks only?

Comment: Why do so many people not like BackgroundWorker?  I like it and find the syntax direct.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is far better than `Thread`, but `Task`-based APIs will eventually dominate. I have [a related blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html). `Task.Run` has the following advantages: (1) allows nesting; (2) cancellation support uses the unified `CancellationToken` system; (3) exceptions are propagated more naturally with a correct call stack; (4) results are retrieved more naturally; (5) uses fewer resources (thread pool instead of dedicated thread).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were pretty close.

```
async void OnTestLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => LongOperation());
}
```

`async` [does not execute a method on a thread pool thread](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

`Task.Run` executes an operation on a thread pool thread and returns a `Task` representing that operation.

If you use `Task.Wait` in an `async` method, you're [doing it wrong](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). You should `await` tasks in `async` methods, never block on them.

Comment: Would there be any difference if you did not use async or await in this specific example?

Comment: @Lukazoid: If you mean just `Task.Run` without `await`ing it, then that would silently swallow all exceptions from `LongOperation`.

Comment: But won't the exceptions be swallowed anyway as `OnTestLoaded` is an `async void`? Ah, from further reading, it seems when using async void, the exception would be rethrown on the `SynchronizationContext` captured at the start, without the async/await, it would be swallowed as you said, is that correct?