# ViewModel changes ignored in very specific scenario

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a method tied to a button that does time consuming thing. So I have created a label and binded it to property to inform user that application is actually doing something.

```cs
private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _viewModel.BottomBarMessage = "Loading..."; //part 1
   //do very long thing, for example
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //wait for 3 seconds to simulate long operation
   _viewModel.BottomBarMessage = "Done."; //part 2
}
```

Issue is `part 1` does not seem to be ever executed. Label switches to `Done` but never to `Loading`.
I have suspected its because UI gets blocked, but changing `Sleep` to be executed as `Task` changes nothing.

Comment: Are you doing your UI operations with `Dispatcher`?

Comment: use await Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep - you are blocking UI thread

Comment: @Aadittya no idea what is this

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev guess I'll try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running long tasks without freezing the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065000/running-long-tasks-without-freezing-the-ui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` - you are blocking UI thread.
Something like:

```
 private async void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    _viewModel.BottomBarMessage = "Loading..."; //part 1
    //do very long thing, for example
    await Task.Delay(3000); 
    _viewModel.BottomBarMessage = "Done."; //part 2
 }
```